# Orientdb Indexes in Clusters

Tags: sql, indexing, orientdb

I'm using document type database in Orientdb 2.0.3.

I have a class A which has an field attr1 and I have created NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX index on that attr1.

Recently I have clustered class A into few clusters named  A_1, A_2, A_3 ...

After that when I'm querying for a record in Class A I have noticed the following:

if I execute a query like this,

```
select from A where attr1 = #10:111 AND ...
```

it uses the index on attr1 and do document reads around 1500 (which gives results pretty fast)

But if I execute a query like this,

```
select from cluster:A_1 where attr1 = #10:111 AND ...
```

it does not use the index on attr1 and do document reads around 14000 (which is the number of records in that cluster)

What I want to know is, whether the way I'm querying the records is incorrect or is there a way I can specifically say use that index even when I'm querying from the cluster.

**Question: If I specify "select from cluster:A_1 ..." does Orientdb ignores the indexes???**

PS: I have rebuild the index also and still the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orientdb still not supporting this feature.

Hopefully they will in the future.

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4606